# JS replace string with slashes

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace the string `/xxx/` with `https://example.com/`

what i'm trying is:

```
link = link.replace('\/xxx\/','https://example.com/');
```

but doesn't wrok

Comment: your code works fine 
```
var link = '/xxx/'
link = link.replace('\/xxx\/','https://example.com/');
console.log(link) ==> "https://example.com/"

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the backslashes. Simply do

```
link = link.replace('/xxx/','https://example.com/');
```

Comment: thanks, i was mistakenly using /xxx/ instead of the actual var which was /xxxs/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work just fine.

```js
let link = "/xxx/foo.html";
link = link.replace('\/xxx\/','https://example.com/');
console.log(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

your code works fine

```
var link = '/xxx/'
link = link.replace('\/xxx\/','https://example.com/');
console.log(link) ==> "https://example.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```js
let link= '/xxx/';
alert('link='+link);
link = link.replace('\/xxx\/','https://example.com/');
alert('link='+link);
```

This works, too:

```js
let link= '/xxx/';
alert('link='+link);
link = link.replace('/xxx/','https://example.com/');
alert('link='+link);
```

Million $$$ question: are you *SURE* that link is "/xxx/" before your "replace()"?